# C6001 : Not initalized storage is being used, although I did that

Tags: c++, pointers, storage

```
  int num = 5;
  int* ptr = new int;
  int** ptr2 = new int*;
  int*** ptr3 = new int**;

  ptr = &num;
  *ptr2 = ptr;
```

This is the line which is giving me an error
I am obviously trying to let ptr3 point to ptr2 but it doesent work because of C6001

```
  **ptr3 = *ptr2;

  std::cout << ***ptr3 << std::endl;

  delete ptr;
  delete *ptr2;
  delete **ptr3;
```

Comment: *"I am obviously trying to let ptr3 point to ptr2"* Well, you may be trying, but you are failing. That would be `ptr3 = &ptr2;`

Comment: Stop using raw pointers and `new` for no concise reasoning with c++.

Comment: _"but it doesent work because of C6001"_ I have no clue what _C6001_means,  but it's probably a good compiler message to notice you that you should stop what you're doing.

Comment: Three-star programming!

Comment: @Eljay Yes, that's what makes tose lost souls to be superior, but totally fails in reality.

Comment: As a rule of thumb; the more stars (`*`) you use, the worse of a C++ programmer you are. The *best* C++ programmers hardly ever use any stars at all, and when they do, they are single stars denoting non-owning pointers. Generalizing wildly of course, but it's not far from the truth. Research containers and smart pointers and stop doing manual memory management.

Answer (score 2):

So the following code achieves what I think you are trying to achieve

```
int num = 5;
int* ptr = &num;
int** ptr2 = &ptr;
int*** ptr3 = &ptr2;
```

Now `ptr3` points at `ptr2`, which points at `ptr`, which points at `num`. But notice there's no allocation here at all.

When you allocate memory the pointer ends up pointing to the allocated memory. In your code it's as if you think that you need to allocate memory for the pointer itself. But that's not true. The pointer gets it's memory just by being declared. It's then up to you to make that pointer point at something, either newly allocated memory or some other variable.

Sometimes it seems to me that all the confusion around pointers is fundamentally because newbies fail to properly distinguish
the pointer and what is being pointed at.

Comment: "Sometimes it seems to me that all the confusion around pointers is fundamentally because newbies fail to properly distinguish the pointer and what is being pointed at." - You are not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

`*ptr3` dereferences `ptr3` - the result is the uninitialized `int**` pointer you earlier allocated with `new int**`; let's call it `X`.

`**ptr3` is equivalent to `*X` - it attempts to dereference that uninitialized pointer, whereby your program exhibits undefined behavior.